# TFS2010 and compile once strategy

Tags: tfs, build-automation

I'm trying to implement a compile once strategy on TFS2010 and I need a little input on how to do this. On CI I want to compile everything (e.g. debug version and a release version) and run unittest. In the next build definition I want to run the integrationtests on the same sat of binaries compiled in CI. The build pipeline could look like the following

checkin -> Step 1 CI: compile + unittest  -> Step 2 Nightly: integration tests -> Step 3 Release: configure and packaging

I'm not sure if it is possible to acquire the last successfull build from another team build from the drop location. This would resolve my problem in step 2, when I need to acquire the precompiled binaries from step 1.

Any general input or suggestions regarding getting the last successful build from another build def?

Comment: FYI, this sort of thing won't work if there are significant differences among builds based on configuration. For instance, using web.config transforms with a web application, you want to build different configurations because they produce different configuration settings.

Comment: Also, do you really have a one to one mapping between your CI builds and your release builds? Usually "n" CI builds eventually produce "m" builds for QA which produce "1" release to Production.

Comment: We don't use web.config transformation for that very same reason. Configuration either happens when packaging the application or when installing. In regards to the pipeline idea, it is of course not a 1-1 mapping. What I'm trying to achieve is that the binaries that I test en dev, devtest, qa etc are also the binaries used or sent to the users. This way I can, with confident, say that the release package and these exact binaries have been testes. It seems that paradigm that most use due to the nature of TFS, is to compile at each step/stage in the build pipeline.

Comment: I used to feel the same way, but I trust that the desired _code_ is being built in each build, which should result in the same binaries, _more or less_. The "more or less" part is that I might _decide_ that I want slightly different settings between the QA and Production builds.

Comment: I agree they should be the same, but why compile each time? Do we gain anything? Regarding configuration we do not do this at compilation time. We either switch out the config file or transform it during deployment (MSBuild) or let WiX configure the settings when installing.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the Step 2 Nightly is not a build definition, it's a console application that:

1. Retrieves the latest succeeding build
2. Grabs the binaries of this build from the build drop location
3. Executes the tests & depending on their success (or not), does certain actions (like sending an emails, or applying a label in source control).

Those actions can also be made in a heavily customized Build Process Template, where major build steps like CreateWorkspace and Run MSBuild are chopped off & the above logic is implemented by hand.
In your place I would go for a C# console application that uses TFS-SDK, does the above & is scheduled to kick-in once a day.

---

**EDIT**
Taking your comments into account, I can't see why my proposal is taking you away from your build pipeline. 
In any case, the heart & sould of Step2 (at least in my understanding) is to retrieve the drop location of a former succeeded build & then execute some actions upon the binaries that reside there.
 This retrieval could look similar to the following:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

namespace GetDropLocationOfLastGoodBuild
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc =
                TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
                    new Uri("TFSURI"));

            IBuildServer buildService = (IBuildServer) tpc.GetService(typeof (IBuildServer));
            IBuildDefinition buildDefinition = buildService.GetBuildDefinition("TeamProject", "BuildDefinitionName");
            Uri buildUri = buildDefinition.LastGoodBuildUri;
            IBuildDetail buildDetail = buildService.GetAllBuildDetails(buildUri);

            String binariesOfLastGoodBuild = buildDetail.DropLocation;
        }
    }
}
```

Having retrieved the drop location, you should be able to commence whatever activities you have planned.
 All details you need are in `buildDetail`.
 Now, this could run as a custom build activity of a highly customized build process template, or as a separate scheduled console app. 
Personally I would do the latter & would set it with Windows Task Scheduler to execute once a day in my buildserver.

Comment: This is a simplified build pipeline for one of our project, since irl it contains multiple steps. I however cannot understand why you would take this step out of the build. I want to create a build pipeline, which contains steps like compile, unit and integration tests, performance tests, load tests, documentation, configuration, packaging and deployment and I want to keep this in the build service. Previously I worked with TeamCity and it had the ability to use 'artifacts' from other successful builds hence a pipeline. Taking certain steps out of the build pipeline just doesnt make sense imho

Comment: I understand your approach and it could be integrated into a TFS build def. Your approach could be used to create a custom task, just to acquire the last successful build of xx. I guess I was hoping for a more 'native' approach. I've found very little information regarding compile once approaches when using TFS20xx. Thanks for the input so far!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you want to provide inputs to a build, there are two approaches :

- copy the results of build 1 to a safe folder outside the normal build folder. Build 2 then copies what it needs back into its working folder.
- check the results of build 1 into tfs, ready for future builds to get and use.

The second strategy is the best, as it means you have historical versions of the binary inputs for every build - you can do historical or branch builds and the build system will use the appropriate versions of everything.

The question that springs to my mind is: why do you want to do compile-once? For CI you should be aiming for an incremental build so you can turn builds around as quickly as possible. For nightly test and release builds you want to rebuild everything from scratch rather than relying on incremental builds to work perfectly (which they never do - eventually the source and binaries get a bit out of sync and the build produces a broken result, or fails to complete).

Comment: Checking the binaries could work, but seems a bit excessive. We get a lot of checkins :).

Comment: In regards to why I want to only build once, is to assure that the same bins are used in each and every stage and finally package/used in production. This assures these exact binaries has been tested (note, not a changeset) and  are release into production. It's one of the principles of continuous delivery by Jez Humble (Excellent book!). http://jamesbetteley.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/continuous-delivery/